# Options for implementing search in .Net web projects?

Tags: asp.net, search, search-engine

I come from a background in Ruby on Rails.  Implementing search is relatively trivia using some of the excellent search plugins available to that community (i.e., Sphinx, Solr, etc.).

In .Net, what's a similar counter part the above strategies? I discovered DotLucene -- but, that project is now closed. Any others I should consider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Comment: Doh! I was spelling it wrong "DotLucene" vs. "Lucene.net" -- thanks Gabriel!